# Почему не работают события нажатия мышки в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Использую функцию OnMouseDown и OnMouseUp, пишу Debug.Log, а ничего не выводится. Также с кодом, он не работает, хотя все было выполнено верно.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    bool MouseOn = false;

    void Start () {

    }
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        MouseOn = true;
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        MouseOn = false;


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 Cursor = Input.mousePosition;
        Cursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Cursor);
        Debug.Log(Cursor);
            if (MouseOn)
        {
            Cursor.z = 0;
            this.transform.position = Cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Читайте документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html). 
OnMouseDown вызывается, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку мыши, находясь над элементом GUIElement или Collider. Это событие отправляется всем сценариям коллайдера или GUIElement.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) { }
}
```

Событие нажатия левой кнопки мыши.